# Use of present perfect "I've gotten up at five o'clock in the morning."

Tags: present-perfect, writing

Here is a sentence I wrote:

> I've gotten up at five o'clock in the morning.

I intend to convey the idea that waking up at five o'clock in the morning is like a daily routine for me both in the past and now. Does this the right way to use present perfect? But my roommate said this sentence sounds like me only doing this action repeatedly in the past, but not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present perfect in your example describes an experience that you have.  Compare

> I've climbed Mt Fuji.  (I have the experience of climbing Mt Fuji)

> I've gotten up at 5am (I have this experience of getting up at 5am)

It suggests "I was able to get up at 5am on one or more occasions in the past, but usually it is too difficult for me to get at that time".

To describe something that happens always use simple present "I get up..."

I suppose you could say:

> I've gotten up at 5am everyday since I was 15, and I'm going to continue doing so.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, and could you tell me how to use present perfect to convey the original idea I have?

Comment: You don't use the present perfect to convey the orginal idea. You use the simple present.

Answer (score 1):

Your roommate is correct. "I get up at five o'clock in the morning" conveys what you want.

Comment: Is that because "at five o'clock in the morning" is a past time?

Comment: @crucifyficklecrank No, it is because it is a habitual action. Those are represented using simple present tense.